# xampp access forbidden error 403

Tags: xampp

Hey fellow developers I have a question that you guys can probably help me out with. Im running xampp 5.6.8.0, and everytime I try to run my registration php file, I get a " access forbidden error 403. You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.  If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster." I've been doing alot of research into finding the solution, and I keep getting the same thing which is "change the denied access to require all granted" I looked into my httpd-xampp file, and they already say require all granted. Here it is...

```
#
# XAMPP settings
#

`<IfModule env_module>
 SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
 SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
 SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
 SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
 SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
 SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php5_module>
PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
<Files "php-cgi.exe">
      Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler cgi-script
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler None
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
<IfModule php5_module>
    <Files "status.php">
        php_admin_flag safe_mode off
    </Files>
</IfModule>
AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
Alias /security "C:/xampp/security/htdocs/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/security/htdocs">
    <IfModule php5_module>
        <Files "xamppsecurity.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

 Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
 <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
    Options +Indexes
    <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
        DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
        DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
        DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
        DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
        DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
    </IfModule>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
   </Directory>

  Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
    <IfModule php5_module>
        <Files "webalizer.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
 </IfModule>

 #
 # New XAMPP security concept
 #
 <LocationMatch "^/(?i:    (?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local

ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```

[apache log info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K1vz.png)

Comment: paste your apache error log as well

Comment: okay I just added it. its right at the bottom. Thank you

Comment: Hey, I found the problem. I went into my config. file and changed require all denied to require all granted

Comment: What do you mean config. file - which file? I have searched all of my config files for "denied" and changed all require all denied to require all granted, and restarted and still can't open localhost/webalizer - I get the access forbidden error,